# Java System Dependence Graph API

Tags: java, dependencies, code-analysis

From what i read on the Net: PDG or SDG can give me a tree of dependecies i tried with a simple exemple but i have no result

what i did :

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException;

import com.graph.element.Node;
import com.graph.internal.NodeNotFoundException;
import com.graph.sdg.SystemDependenceGraph;;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, AnalyzerException, NodeNotFoundException {
        SystemDependenceGraph lvSystemDependenceGraph 
        =new SystemDependenceGraph("C:\\Users\\amina\\workspace\\SDG\\fact","C:\\Users\\amina\\workspace\\SDG\\fact\\bin\\Fact.class");
Iterator<Node> lvIterator =lvSystemDependenceGraph.controlDependenceBFSIterator();
    while (lvIterator.hasNext()) {
        Node lvNode = lvIterator.next();

    }
    }

}
```

class fact :

```
public class Fact {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int f;
        int n;
        n=4;
        f=1;
        while(n!=0){
            f=f*n;
            n=n-1;
        }
        System.out.println("f= "+f+" n= "+n);
    }

}
```

when i run class A there is no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDG is a java library for analyzing java code. It processes the java sources/byte code, converts into a graph. If you iterate with either BFS or DFS, it gives you series of instruction(code) including the callee method instructions.

In the above example,  Class A is iterating over the instructions. Every Node is a instruction there. After retrieving node, you are not printing it so there is no output for the above class.

If you add below line, then it works.

```
   System.out.println("Instruction is " + node.getName());
```

There are other methods in the Node class like sourceline(getLine()), source is a caller or not (getCaller), what is the instruction type (getType()) etc...